# Push notification GCM DELPHI XE8

Tags: android, delphi, google-cloud-messaging

To send a push I use json:

```
‘{"registration_ids":["' + Edit1.Text + '"],"data":{"id":"0","Message":"‘ + Edit2.Text + ‘"}}’
```

The push is receiving in the push panel normal and opening program too. Also I can read the text inside of client-programm. 
The problem is, I have no the text of message in the push panel. Only name of the client program.

Answer (score 3):

Solved! I used "message" instead of "Message".

Answer (score 2):

To display information in the push panel you should give that information in the notification payload:

```
‘{"registration_ids":["' + Edit1.Text + '"],
  "data":{"id":"0", "Message":"' + Edit2.Text + '"},
  "notification":{"title":"MyTitle", "body":"' + Edit2.Text + '"}}'
```

Comment: You forget " after notification. I checked your code - nothing. It's working in the same way...the push is sending and no text in the panel, only name of project...